# How do I go about ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, class

```java
public class Point {
    int x, y;
    Point() { System.out.println("default"); }
    Point(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }

    static Point origin = new Point(0,0);

    public String toString() { return "(" + x + "," + y + ")"; }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p = null;
        try {
            p = (Point)Class.forName("Point").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        Point a[] = { new Point(0,0), new Point(1,1) };
        System.out.println("p: " + p);
        System.out.println("a: { " + a[0] + ", " + a[1] + " }");
    }
}
```

It is supposed to produce:

default
p: (0,0)
a: { (0,0), (1,1) }

But it produced:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Point
p: null
a: { (0,0), (1,1) }

Comment: You need to give the fully qualified name to `Class.forName()`. So `Class.forName("my.package.Point");`.

Comment: Beautiful. It worked! GG @Kayaman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the fully qualified name solved the problem. For me, `main` is the name of the package:
`p = (Point)Class.forName("main.Point").newInstance();`